# list() wrap array in another array php

Tags: php, arrays

Why `list()` method using two array (array of arrays) as values don't work (for one specific array ($subCategories) the list wrap in another array, the other array is output equals before list()).

list method:

```
list($subCategories, $subCategoriesName) = [$subCategories, $subCategoriesName]; //[array, array]
```

> `[$subCategories, $subCategoriesName]` are the return of a function

**$subCategories before list**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["sub_category_name"]=>
    string(14) "Industrilizado"
    ["category_id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["sub_category_name"]=>
    string(9) "In natura"
    ["category_id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(3)
    ["sub_category_name"]=>
    string(13) "Comida pronta"
    ["category_id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["sub_category_name"]=>
    string(11) "Desidratado"
    ["category_id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

**$subCategories after list**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["sub_category_name"]=>
      string(14) "Industrilizado"
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["sub_category_name"]=>
      string(9) "In natura"
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(3)
      ["sub_category_name"]=>
      string(13) "Comida pronta"
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(4)
      ["sub_category_name"]=>
      string(11) "Desidratado"
      ["category_id"]=>
      int(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will be.... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @MarkBaker separate each value of the array passed to list() in a separate variable, note the `$subCategoriesName` is array to but not was wrapped

Comment: Well you could perhaps use [extract()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) instead..... but it's really better working with arrays than with a set of individual variables

Comment: `[$subCategories, $subCategoriesName]` each position of the array need to be an individual array

Comment: Yes, and try extract()..... that will create an individual set of variables for each element of the array..... but it's still not a good idea

Comment: Another question why the second array have no changes ?

Comment: For exactly the same reason as the first array has no changes..... effectively, what you're saying with `list($subCategories, $subCategoriesName) = [$subCategories, $subCategoriesName];` is `$subCategories = $subCategories; $subCategoriesName = $subCategoriesName;`

Comment: but the first array `$subCategories` was wrapped and the second `$subCategoriesName` not; like this: `$subCategories[0] = $subCategories;` $subCategoriesName = $subCategoriesName;``

Comment: Then something else you've done has made that change.... I've told you what your list() did